# dynamiclly create shell command

Tags: shell, unix

I have following array

```
arg[1]=mks
value[1]="12 ds"
arg[2]=bsk
value[2]="ds 54"
arg[3]=dkd
value[3]="dd 65"
```

I don't want to use any other variable or an array and I want to generate the  command dynamically for n number of values in below format

```
command mycommand /path/location ${arg[1]}="${value[1]}" ${arg[2]}="${value[2]}" ...
```

How to do this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use another array? I can think of a clean solution with an array, and of ugly hacks in escaping hell without an array.

Comment: Do you want `command mycommand /path/location mks="12 ds" bsk="ds 54" dkd="dd"`?